# error provider is not blinking uniformly

Tags: c#, winforms, errorprovider

I have an error provider providing error for 4 controls..

when I set all the four errors, only two of them blink together at a time and all four settle down after certain time..

even if I set two errors, both blink alternatively..

but I want all of them blink together...How can I do this? (I don't prefer using more than one errorProvider)

Comment: One very good solution would be `Blinking=false`.

Comment: I'd do a quick cost/benefit analysis and mark it as 'wont-fix'.

Comment: Henk is right; blinking shouldn't be necessary. If the mere presence of the steady red error provider glyph isn't enough to draw attention to the control, then your UI is probably too cluttered. On a well designed form, that glyph should stand out.

Comment: Blinking isn't _necessary_ but if it's allowed I'd expect it to work properly (i.e. blink in unison by default). Just got bitten by this too, will probably just give in and remove the blink...

Answer (score 0):

You've hinted to an (IMO) acceptable solution, with your last statement: use 2 error providers, one dedicated to blinking exactly one control at a time (the latest one with an invalid input, or the one you'd expect to be corrected ASAP, or whatever criteria you deem most important), and a second one that "silently" displays the icon on all controls with invalid input.